# Clickhouse nested map: get specified with total

Tags: select, nested, clickhouse

Clickhouse table with nested map:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test.NestedTest2
(
    -- slices
    idx1 UInt8, -- just some index 1
    idx2 UInt8, -- just some index 2

    -- metrics
    totalCnt UInt64,  -- total http response count
    codeMap Nested(
        key UInt16,   -- http response code
        value UInt64  -- http response count
    )

) Engine MergeTree()
PARTITION BY (idx1)
ORDER BY (idx1, idx2)


INSERT INTO Test.NestedTest2 (idx1, idx2, totalCnt, codeMap.key, codeMap.value) 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 5, array(200), array(5))
    (1, 1, 5, array(204), array(5))
    (1, 1, 15, array(404, 502), array(5, 10))
    (1, 2, 45, array(404, 502), array(20, 25))
    (2, 1, 20, array(404, 502, 200), array(5, 5, 10))
```

Where `totalCnt` only as example. Same way it may by related to total value, such as `memoryUsage`.

I need to get specific code response count within the total responses in the same select:

```sql
-- where idx1 = 1
/*
┌─code─┬─count─┬─totalCnt─┐
│  200 │     5 │       70 │
│  204 │     5 │       70 │
│  404 │    25 │       70 │
│  502 │    35 │       70 │
└──────┴───────┴──────────┘
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    idx1,
    (arrayJoin(arrayMap((x, y) -> (x, y), (sumMap(codeMap.key, codeMap.value) AS a).1, a.2)) AS arr).1 AS code,
    arr.2 AS cnt,
    sum(totalCnt) AS total
FROM Test.NestedTest2
WHERE idx1 = 1
GROUP BY idx1

┌─idx1─┬─code─┬─cnt─┬─total─┐
│    1 │  200 │   5 │    70 │
│    1 │  204 │   5 │    70 │
│    1 │  404 │  25 │    70 │
│    1 │  502 │  35 │    70 │
└──────┴──────┴─────┴───────┘
```

BTW, you can calculate `total` from `codeMap.value` -- `arrayReduce('sum', groupArrayArray`

```
SELECT
    idx1,
    (arrayJoin(arrayMap((x, y) -> (x, y), (sumMap(codeMap.key, codeMap.value) AS a).1, a.2)) AS arr).1 AS code,
    arr.2 AS cnt,
    arrayReduce('sum', groupArrayArray(codeMap.value)) AS total
FROM Test.NestedTest2
WHERE idx1 = 1
GROUP BY idx1

┌─idx1─┬─code─┬─cnt─┬─total─┐
│    1 │  200 │   5 │    70 │
│    1 │  204 │   5 │    70 │
│    1 │  404 │  25 │    70 │
│    1 │  502 │  35 │    70 │
└──────┴──────┴─────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

This way isn't perfect because of `ARRAY JOIN` (grafana ad hoc filters desn't works with such queries).

```sql
SELECT idx1, code, val, total
FROM (

    SELECT
        idx1,
        sumMap(codeMap.key, codeMap.value) as arr,
        sum(totalCnt) as total
    FROM Test.NestedTest2
    WHERE idx1 = 1
    GROUP BY idx1

)
ARRAY JOIN arr.1 as code, arr.2 as val
ORDER BY idx1, code
/*
┌─idx1─┬─code─┬─val─┬─total─┐
│    1 │  200 │   5 │    70 │
│    1 │  204 │   5 │    70 │
│    1 │  404 │  25 │    70 │
│    1 │  502 │  35 │    70 │
└──────┴──────┴─────┴───────┘
*/
```